# Connecting to Cassandra KEYSPACE created in CQL 3

Tags: cassandra

I created a KEYSPACE using cassandra cql3 and am trying to connect to the same using Cassandra jdbc driver.  When I try to do so I get the error:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace MYKEYSPACE does not exist)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.(CassandraConnection.java:139)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:92)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)

The connection string is: jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/MYKEYSPACE ?version=3.0.0

I can connect and check that the keyspace exists from command line. (cqlsh -3 localhost 9160); use KEYSPACE MYKEYSPACE

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: JDBC is being case-sensitive.  Try lowercase.

Comment: It should not make a difference. The Keyspace is defined upper case. You were right.. That sounds like a bug to me:-(

Comment: It's not; CQL 3 is defined as downcasing identifiers by default (similar to how several RMDBS systems try to avoid case mismatches). You can double-quote words to avoid that.